# SharePoint Visual Webparts development

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am creating visual studio web part and deploying that solutions. It is going to add that solution or feature in Central admin site. I want to deploy my solutions and features to my site collection, how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would be helpful, like if you are trying to create a farm solution or sandbox solution, SharePoint 2010 or 2013. Anyway I assume you are creating a farm solution.

When you create a web part and add the solution (suppose through stsadm command or powershell) it will appear in Central Administration i.e. you have to do the deployment from central administration (you can use command for deployment too). Now I understand that your requirement is to deploy the feature in site collection, in that case feature scope should be 'Site'. Please check in your feature definition xml if Scope attribute is something other than 'Site'. If the scope is 'Site' you can build, add, deploy the solution and then check your site collection feature for the required feature and activate the feature.

Comment: Thank you Diptaraq. I am using sahrepoint 2013, Farm solution. I followed your way and added that webpart into my site collection. I can see my web part in the web part categories list. Thank you! When I add my custom webparts to my page. it is throwing error Web part maintance error.

Comment: That error may be related to your custom code. Can you please post the error details?

Comment: Erro log file is too long.. Sorry I dont know where to find the error message. I tried with Correlation id. it is there every where

Comment: help me how to trace this error in log file